# check key is present in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the "data" dict

```
{' node2': {'Status': ' online', 'TU': ' 900', 'Link': ' up', 'Port': ' a0a-180', 'MTU': ' 9000'}, ' node1': {'Status': ' online', 'TU': ' 900', 'Link': ' up', 'Port': ' a0a-180', 'MTU': ' 9000'}}
```

I am trying key node2 is present or not in data dict in  below code but it is not working. Please help

```
if 'node2' in data:
    print "node2 Present"
else:
    print "node2Not present"
```

Comment: Check your dictionary. Some keys have a leading space.

Comment: Is there a space in`' node2'`?

Comment: When you say 'it is not working', what result are you getting, exactly? The code you are checking with looks like it should work, so maybe the problem is in the code around it - could you post that here, so we can see what else might be causing a problem?

Comment: `If data.get(' node2',None)`

Comment: @akashkarothiya that will result in a ``KeyError`` if the key does not exist!

Comment: Added space now it is working. Thanks a lot

Comment: @mpf82 nope, `get` with return its second argument if the key isn't present in the dictionary.

Comment: @holdenweb The original comment was ``if data[' node2']`` (which would result in a KeyError, as I pointed out). Using ``d.get(key, fallback)`` is fine ofc. @akashkarothiya changed the comment afterwards.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'node2' in data:
    print "node2 Present"
else:
    print "node2Not present"
```

This is a perfectly appropriate way of determining if a key is inside a dictionary, unfortunately `'node2'` is not in your dictionary, `' node2'` is (note the space):

```
if ' node2' in data:
    print "node2 Present"
else:
    print "node2Not present"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check key is present in dictionary :**

```
data = {'node2': {'Status': ' online', 'TU': ' 900', 'Link': ' up', 'Port': ' a0a-180', 'MTU': ' 9000'}, ' node1': {'Status': ' online', 'TU': ' 900', 'Link': ' up', 'Port': ' a0a-180', 'MTU': ' 9000'}}
```

**In python 2.7 version:**

[has_key()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key)-Test for the presence of key in the dictionary.

```
if data.has_key('node2'):
    print("found key") 
  else:
    print("invalid key")
```

**In python 3.x version:**

`key in d` - Return True if d has a key, else False.

```
  if 'node2' in data:
    print("found key") 
  else:
    print("invalid key")
```

Comment: You should point out ``has_key`` is removed in Python 3.x (and it's not very pythonic anyway). Source: [Removed. dict.has_key() – use the in operator instead.](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) [I realize the question is flagged "python-2.7", but for the sake of completeness it should be pointed out] - but the "problem" in OP's question is the space in the key.